# Android: onActionViewExpanded how hide soft keyboard when start fragment?

Tags: android, searchview

I has fragment with **searchView** (not in ToolBar). I want it to be always expand.
So I use method

```
searchView.onActionViewExpanded();
```

OK. It's work. After start fragment the **searchView** is expand and soft keyboad is show.

But I need to expand seachcView withou show keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `searchView.clearFocus();` after `searchView.onActionViewExpanded();` as follows.
(But some time that is not working.)

```
searchView.onActionViewExpanded();
searchView.clearFocus();
```

The following code helps me.

```
searchView.onActionViewExpanded();

searchView.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          searchView.clearFocus();
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this may be it help

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```